# Как указать цвет для svg маркера google карт?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Создаю маркер размером 32 на 32 пикселя из svg файла. Но он получается черного цвета. Как ему указать цвет?

```
new google.maps.MarkerImage('/image.svg',
                                                        null,
                                                        null,
                                                        null,
                                                        new google.maps.Size(32, 32))
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Попробуй свойство `fill` или `stroke`

У SVG элементов для задания цвета и цвета обводки используются свойства `fill` или `stroke`

Соответственно background-color работать не будет.

Прочитать про это подробнее можно тут

http://css.yoksel.ru/svg-fill-and-stroke/

Пример

`svg#my-svg {
  fill: red,
  stroke: green
}`

Comment: Пожалуйста, распишите ваш ответ подробнее, приведите пример и всё такое